# Update ObservableCollection UI

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a ObservableCollection binding in xaml and I can't update UI when I use "Add" element, the element is added to the list but doesn't appear on UI.

If I do new ObservableCollection with the elements the UI is updated, but I want to use Add and update the view.

```
public ObservableCollection<ResourcePreviewViewViewModel> AttatchResource
    {
        get { return attatchResource; }
        set
        {
            attatchResource = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("AttatchResource");              
        }
    }
```

I added a event to when collection is changed:

```
public void ContentCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {          
        OnPropertyChanged("AttatchResource");                
    }
```

To add the elements to list:

```
AttatchResource.Add(new ResourcePreviewViewViewModel());
```

My UI binding:

```
<suave:DynamicStackLayout ItemsSource="{Binding AttatchResource}"                                                  
                          HorizontalOptions="Fill" 
                          Orientation="Horizontal">
<suave:DynamicStackLayout.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <localcontrol:ResourcePreviewView />
    </DataTemplate>
</suave:DynamicStackLayout.ItemTemplate>
```

I don't know what to try more, what can I do to update the UI ?

Comment: How do you add something to the collection? How do you bind your collection to the UI? It might help to add some more relevant code for us to look at :)

Comment: @GeraldVersluis It's a simply binding and add, but I updated my code on the question

Comment: I see that you are using a custom control. When I look up the GitHub page I see there is an outstanding issue for this: https://github.com/SuavePirate/DynamicStackLayout/issues/6 so you're probably not going to be able to solve it unless you do it in that project directly and contribute the code :)

Comment: @GeraldVersluis that explain why I can't found a solution!! Thanks for the help